# Rselenium driver methods inside a function

Tags: r, rselenium

I am trying to use some methods like `sendKeysToElement()` inside a function. My problem is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40821076/r-passing-rselenium-driver-environment-as-function-argument) but even if I pass the reference remote drive as a function argument, I still get an error. I have no problem in executing this code when not a function.

```
question <- "Which hormone concentrations are altered in patients with the Allan Herndon Dudley syndrome?"

searchMM <- function(x, remDr){
  remDr$findElement("css","textarea")$clearElement()
  remDr$findElement("css","textarea")$sendKeysToElement(list(x))
  remDr$findElement("css", "#note > input[type='button']:nth-child(12)")$clickElement()
  concept <- remDr$findElement("css","table:nth-child(31) pre")$getElementText()
  remDr$goBack()
  concept <- unlist(concept)
  test <- unlist(str_split(concept, "\n"))
}

searchMM(x=question, remDr=remDr)
test
```

After running the function, when I try to see what's in `test`, I get `Error: object 'test' not found`. For that matter, `concept` also doesn't exist. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You dont have a return statement inside your function You could for example create list called output <- list(concept, test). Then return(output). Also,  you are not saving anything to the object test outside your function, therefor it is empty.

Comment: Thanks @MLEN for pointing that out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
question <- "Which hormone concentrations are altered in patients with the Allan Herndon Dudley syndrome?"

searchMM <- function(x, remDr){
  remDr$findElement("css","textarea")$clearElement()
  remDr$findElement("css","textarea")$sendKeysToElement(list(x))
  remDr$findElement("css", "#note > input[type='button']:nth-child(12)")$clickElement()
  concept <- remDr$findElement("css","table:nth-child(31) pre")$getElementText()
  remDr$goBack()
  concept <- unlist(concept)
  test <- unlist(str_split(concept, "\n"))

output <- list(test,concept)
return(output)
}

test <- searchMM(x=question, remDr=remDr)
```